# alternative for stored procedure in mysql which can be altered

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

1.) alternative for stored procedure in mysql which can be altered  rather than drop and create again

2.) easy ways to maintain database version 
i am currently creating log.sql files manually such as
example log.sql file

```
    ALTER TABLE `ship` 
    CHANGE COLUMN `is_deleted` `is_deleted` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT 0 ;
    DROP procedure IF EXISTS `get_ship`;
    DELIMITER ;;
    CREATE PROCEDURE `get_ship`(

    )
    BEGIN
     do something;    
    end if;
    END ;;
    DELIMITER ;
```

Is there an better and easy way to create such sql log files,
I have already tried MYSQL workbench

Comment: possible duplicate of [stored procedure alternative in mysql which can be altered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526041/stored-procedure-alternative-in-mysql-which-can-be-altered)

Comment: @MikeW yes i posted this question before but had no comments for many days so add a new question as given in Ur link .. but still have no correct answer yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as you create stored procedures using the CREATE PROCEDURE command, you alter them with ALTER PROCEDURE. The advantage of using ALTER PROCEDURE to change a stored procedure is that it preserves access permissions, whereas CREATE PROCEDURE doesn't. A key difference between them is that ALTER PROCEDURE requires the use of the same encryption and recompile options as the original CREATE PROCEDURE statement. If you omit or change them when you execute ALTER PROCEDURE, they'll be omitted or changed permanently in the actual procedure definition.

A procedure can contain any valid Transact-SQL command except these: CREATE DEFAULT, CREATE FUNCTION, CREATE PROC, CREATE RULE, CREATE SCHEMA, CREATE TRIGGER, CREATE VIEW, SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT, and SET SHOWPLAN_ALL. These commands must reside in their own command batches, and, therefore, can't be part of a stored procedure. Procedures can create databases, tables, and indexes, but not other procedures, defaults, functions, rules, schemas, triggers, or views

but u could try out views in mysql for u case