# stored procedure alternative in mysql which can be altered

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

1.) alternative for stored procedure in mysql which can be altered rather than drop and create again

2.) easy ways to maintain database version i am currently creating log.sql files manually such as example log.sql file

```
ALTER TABLE `ship` 
CHANGE COLUMN `is_deleted` `is_deleted` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT 0 ;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `get_ship`;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE `get_ship`(

)
BEGIN
 do something;    
end if;
END ;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Is there an better and easy way to create such sql log files,
I have already tried MYSQL workbench

Answer (score 0):

When you are redefining a table structure with any of the following

1. drop column,
2. change column,
3. modify column,
4. add column,
5. rename table

and your stored procedure has dependency on the same table and its pre-defined columns,
then you don't have a choice but redefine part of your stored procedure.

And this can only be achieved by dropping and re-creating the procedure again.

As per documentation on [*`ALTER PROCEDURE Syntax`*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-procedure.html), in MySQL,

> *However, you cannot change the parameters or body of a stored procedure using this statement; to make such changes, you must drop and re-create the procedure using DROP PROCEDURE and CREATE PROCEDURE.*

`add column` may not require re-building your stored procedure unless the new column too participates in the procedure's algorithm.

Comment: so is there an alternative for it like function , cursor ..etc maybe

Comment: and any idea about the log file maintenance in mysql versions
&& thanks alot for ur feedback